# IIS7.5 is only resolving to the Default Web Site

Tags: iis-7.5

I am able to access only the Default Web Site on a Windows 2008 R2 Server which is running IIS 7.5

The Default Web Site's binding is to "All Unassigned", same way as I have done it on a different machine running IIS6 under Windows 2003 Server.  The bindings of the desired Web Site have the IP address of the server and the correct home directory.

Regardless what I do, the only page content I can see is the default index page in the wwwroot directory which is the Default Web Site.

What must I do to deliver the correct content from the Web Sites that are configured in IIS7.5?

Comment: How are you accessing the site? By name or ip address?

Answer (score 3):

Beside correct home directory, you have to configure:

1. IP address
2. Port
3. Host name

Wildcards are allowed, but at least one of these things has to be unique (in your case: different from Default web site bindings)

Comment: `Host Header` is the `Hostname`, right?

Comment: Ah, true, they renamed it in iis7. I will edit the answer, thanks.